# $\{g_n\}$ be uniformly bounded sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ and converges pointwise to $g$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

My question is -suppose $\{g_n\}$ be uniformly bounded sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ and converges pointwise to a function. Then can I say $\int_{0}^{1} |g_n(x)-g(x)| dx\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?
If I can conclude $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly to $g$, then I easily say that the above statement is true.
I first thought that uniform boundedness may imply uniform convergence but it is not true (example: $g_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$, it is uniformly bounded by $1$). 
I can't prove or disprove the statements.
Can anybody answer the question? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: I think the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem might give you the result you seek. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: Your example of x$^{n}$ does not converge uniformly but your conclusion holds true anyway because $\int_{0}^{1}$ x$^{n}$ dx = $\frac{1}{n+1}$ $\rightarrow$ 0

Comment: Are your functions integrables at $[0,1]$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: They are uniformly bounded, so the answer will be yes as soon as they are measurable.

Comment: The answer is no, because you've give so little information on the $g_n.$

Comment: ^ profound. Could you improve your question so that the functions are somehow assumed to be measurable?? Btw, if the functions happen to be measurable, we may also say the sequence converges almost uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $g$ by Egoroff's Theorem...the fact that $\mu\left([0,1]\right)=1<\infty$ is important (reasons a dominating function would be integrable). If the interval was not bounded, then there would be examples showing the statement is false (in the context of continuous or measurable functions).